# What global planners come with a ROS Indigo installation?

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, pathplanning, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking into writing simple global planners for a turtlebot 2.

I have looked up other questions and seen that switching out global planners is as easy as changing the value of a parameter in the move_base.launch.xml file.

What I would like to know before carrying on is what global planners already exist on the system? (Base Turtlebot Indigo ROS)

I'd like to know, so that I can examine how these other planner shave been written before going on to trying my hand at writing one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240812/what-global-planners-come-with-a-ros-indigo-installation?/) by [TortoiseTom](https://answers.ros.org/users/27649/tortoisetom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check using this command `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core`

That will list all the plugins that use nav_core as the base. Some are local planners, and some are global.

I'm pretty sure the global planners that come with indigo are global_planner, navfn and carrot_planner. You can check all their details out on their wiki pages:

- http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner
- http://wiki.ros.org/navfn
- http://wiki.ros.org/carrot_planner

---

Originally posted by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) with karma: 261 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TortoiseTom](https://answers.ros.org/users/27649/tortoisetom/) on 2016-08-05**:
Thank you! I didn't realise rospack could be used to check plugins as well as package info